# How to create sql database for teleconferencing?

Tags: mysql, sql

After creating the database it show error after loading below is the report

### Error

#### SQL query:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW  `conference`.`FriendList` AS SELECT  `f`.`userID` AS  `userID` ,  `f`.`frndID` AS  `frndID` ,  `d`.`Image` AS  `Image` 
FROM (

`conference`.`UserDetails`  `d` 
JOIN  `conference`.`usr_frns`  `f`
)
WHERE (
(
`f`.`Accepted` =1
)
AND (
`d`.`UserName` =  `root`.`frndID`
)
);
```

#### MySQL said:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'root.frndID' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: What is `root`, is a table?

Comment: should I send you the sql i created so that you help me to check for the error

Comment: please help me fix and send me the sql file https://www.sendspace.com/file/ef0dv2

Comment: Please, use [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and post the structure of your tables with some test data so we can help you better.